# How to retrieve or enumerate ISO-3166 numeric codes?

Tags: winapi, locale, iso-3166

With `EnumSystemLocalesEx` I can enumerate supported countries and get the ISO-3166-Alpha 2 code.

With `GetLocaleInfoEx` I can retrieve the language name and the ISO-3166-Alpha 3 code. The list of information I can get does not contain the ISO-3166 numeric value, or I missed it and it hides behind a value I can't understand.

I found LOCALE_SISO3166CTRYNAME, LOCALE_SISO3166CTRYNAME2.

Is there a way to to retrieve the [ISO-3166-Numeric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_numeric) value with any of the Windows API function too, when I have a given ISO Alpha 2 or Alpha 3 code?

**Edit:** Code should work for Windows Vista and later!

Comment: [`EnumSystemGeoID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317826) enumerates the system's geographic location IDs. In Windows 8 and later, the 3-digit ISO code is the `GEO_ISO_UN_NUMBER` [`SYSGEOTYPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374071).

Comment: The function exists since XP. I need this for Vista and later. Does the ID is different in the different Windows versions?

Comment: `GEO_ISO_UN_NUMBER` isn't available prior to Windows 8.